# Check if YouTube channel uploaded a video

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, discord, discord.js

I've been looking for quite awhile on how to do this, but I probably missed it somewhere. Is there a way to check if a YouTube channel uploaded a new video, then return the link? I'm in the progress of making a discord.js bot for a YouTuber, and one of his request's was to send a message to a channel whenever his channel uploads a new video alerting everyone to it. There were a couple other things, but I can do them on my own. This is the only thing I haven't been able to find out how to do.

Comment: Maybe? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install this discord youtube API npm package below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-youtube-api

Installation: `npm install --save discord-youtube-api`

Example:

```
 
const youtube = new YouTube("google api key");
 
async function testAll() {
    const video1 = await youtube.getVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NPBIwQyPWE");
    const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID("5NPBIwQyPWE");
    const video3 = await youtube.searchVideos("big poppa biggie smalls");
    const videoArray1 = await youtube.getPlaylist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxyf3paml4dNMlJURcEOND0StDN1Q4yWz");
    const videoArray2 = await youtube.getPlaylistByID("PLxyf3paml4dNMlJURcEOND0StDN1Q4yWz");
 
    console.log(video1, video2, video3, videoArray1, videoArray2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not sure of a way to do this purely from a JS perspective, the way I did a similar thing was using ITTT.

I'm not promoting it or anything just suggesting it as an option, as it basically does somethig when a condition is met (IE new youtube upload) and you can set it to do all sorts.

Might be worth checking out?

https://ifttt.com/

Comment: ifttt is not free. its a subscription base service.